# Change font size of a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, font-size

in WPF It it possible to change a text box's font size during runtime?

i tried to do that:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in gridArray[i].Children)
 {
    if(ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        (TextBox)ctrl.FontSize = (double)5;

    }
 }
```

but it didnt work

Comment: If something *"does not work"* you should describe how so, i.e. what exactly happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast does not have a high precedence, your code effectively tries to cast the value in `ctrl.FontSize` to `TextBox`, you need to add parenthesis (and the double cast is superfluous):

```
((TextBox)ctrl).FontSize = 5;
```

Further the way you check the type of the control is not such a good idea, use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) instead. Otherwise sublasses of `TextBox` are not included.

```
if (ctrl is TextBox)
```

Further as you do not only care about the type and cast as well to interact with the `TextBox` class interface you may as well use [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
var textBox = ctrl as TextBox;
if (textBox != null)
    textBox.FontSize = 5;
```

This also conveniently gets rid of the parenthesis jungle.